# Create interaction variables in SAS

Tags: sas

Is there a way to automatically create interaction variables in SAS? I have over 125 variables and I'm trying to fit the best logistic model. Would it be easier to do a loop in another language (such as Python)?

Comment: I suspect you'll need to provide a bit more detail than this, though perhaps one of the more statistics-savvy folks will see this as a straightforward question.  Would be nice to see an example of what kind of regression/etc. you're doing for example - a sashelp.heart or something example would be even better.

Comment: You can just use var1*var2 if you're using proc glmselect. Afraid you'll need to loop through using the SAS macro language for proc logistic though.

Comment: Please define your question in more detail. Are you trying to create variables, or specify interaction terms in a model statement. If the latter, which PROC are you using? Are all vars numeric or are there categorical vara?